# For what values of x does the series $1+\frac{x}{3}+\frac{x^2}{5}+\frac{x^3}{7}+\cdot\cdot\cdot$ converge?

Tags: power-series

For what values of x does the series $1+\frac{x}{3}+\frac{x^2}{5}+\frac{x^3}{7}+\cdot\cdot\cdot$ converge?

**The solution states:**
The general term is of the form $u_n(x)=\frac{x^{n-1}}{(2n-1)}$, and hence
$$\frac{|u_{n+1}|}{|u_n|}=\frac{|x^n|}{(2n+1)}\cdot\frac{(2n-1)}{|x^{n-1}|}$$
------edit start-------
$$=\frac{(2n-1)}{(2n+1)}\cdot\frac{|x^n|}{|x^{n-1}|}$$
------ edit end -------
$$=\frac{(2n-1)}{(2n+1)}|x|$$
clearly
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|u_{n+1}|}{|u_n|}=|x|$$

My question is:

1. How do you get from $1+\frac{x}{3}+\frac{x^2}{5}+\frac{x^3}{7}+\cdot\cdot\cdot$ to $u_n(x)=\frac{x^{n-1}}{(2n-1)}$?
2. Why do the absolute restriction only apply to the $|x^n|$ and $|x^{n-1}|$ in the next line and not to the rest of the equation?
3. and lastly, We go from $=\frac{(2n-1)}{(2n+1)}\cdot\frac{|x^n|}{|x^{n-1}|}$ to $=\frac{(2n-1)}{(2n+1)}|x|$ I.E. how does $\frac{|x^n|}{|x^{n-1}|}=|x|$ in the next line? (I understand that once you apply the limits, that $\frac{(2n-1)}{(2n+1)} = 1$)

**Edits**
I have added a line to the equation that was not there earlier and clarified my last question.

Comment: For 1: it's one of those patterns you notice; you see the odd numbers in the denominator, and the nonnegative integers as powers, so...

Comment: For 2: the thing that was taken out of the absolute value sign is alright, since it's always positive for $n > 0$.

Comment: For 3: $$\left|\frac{a}{b}\right|=\frac{|a|}{|b|}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. They are defining the terms of your sum. $u_1(x)=\frac{x^{1-1}}{2-1}=1$ and $u_2(x)=\frac{x^{2-1}}{4-1}=\frac{x}{3}$ and $u_3(x)=\frac{x^{3-1}}{6-1}=\frac{x^2}{5}$ and so on and so forth.

2.$|u_n|=\left|\frac{x^n}{2n+1}\right|$ but since $2n+1>0$ because we are dealing in positive integers then we can remove the absolute value around them resulting in $|u_n|=\frac{|x^n|}{2n+1}$ similar reasoning for $u_{n+1}$

3.basic exponent rules for division and a little bit of absolute value rules thrown in $\frac{|x^n|}{|x^{n-1}|}=\frac{|x|^n}{|x|^{n-1}}=|x|$

Comment: On point 3:  
Aaaaa, so:  
$$\frac{x^n}{x^{n-1}} = \frac{x^n}{x^n \cdot x^{-1}}$$
So, the two $x^n$'s cancel out leaving
$$=\frac{1}{x^{-1}}$$
$$=x$$

Thanks. Highschool math :-\.

Answer (score 3):

Let me deal with your second and third questions first, as they're easier. For (2), there is no need to put absolute value signs around $2n-1$ or $2n+1$, because both of these expressions are non-negative already: $n\ge 1$. For (3), the line in question does **not** say that $\frac{|x^n|}{|x^{n-1}|}=|x|$: it says $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|u_{n+1}|}{|u_n|}=|x|\;.$$ Note the limit: it's essential! This can be expanded as follows: $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|u_{n+1}|}{|u_n|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}|x|=|x|\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}=|x|\cdot 1=|x|\;,$$ since $|x|$ is a constant with respect to the limit over $n$.

Now let's look at your first question. You have the series $1+\frac{x}{3}+\frac{x^2}{5}+\frac{x^3}{7}+\dots$, and you want to know how to determine that the $n$-th term, $u_n(x)$, is $\frac{x^{n-1}}{2n-1}$. First, note that whether or not you could have worked this out yourself, you can easily verify that it's correct. The formula gives $\frac{x^{1-1}}{2\cdot1-1}=\frac11=1$ for the first term, which is correct. Each time you increase $n$ by $1$ in the formula for $u_n(x)$, the exponent in the numerator increases by $1$, and the denominator increases by $2$; since that's exactly what's happening in the series $1+\frac{x}{3}+\frac{x^2}{5}+\frac{x^3}{7}+\dots$, and since the formula gets the first term right, it must get **every** term right.

How would you come up with the formula yourself? You might notice that the exponents in the numerator are increasing by $1$ each term; that suggests something like $x^n$. However, the exponent in the first term is $0$, that in the second term is $1$, and so on: the exponent is always one less than the term number, so the numerator of the $n$-th is actually $x^{n-1}$. The denominators are $1,3,5,7,\dots$, increasing by $2$ each time. This suggests that the denominator is something like $2n$, which increases by $2$ every time $n$ is increased by $1$. But this would make the denominators $2,4,6,8,\dots$, exactly one more than we want, so we subtract one: the denominator of the $n$-th term is $2n-1$. And that gives us the formula: the $n$-th term is $\frac{x^{n-1}}{2n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x^0}{1}+\frac{x^1}{3}+\frac{x^2}{5}+\frac{x^3}{7}+\cdot\cdot\cdot$$

You can see the pattern,  in the numerator It's:
$$x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3, \dots, x^{n-1}$$
And in the denominator, it's the odd numbers:
$$1, 3, 5, 7, 9, \dots, 2n-1$$

Therefore, it is:

$$u_n(x)=\frac{x^{n-1}}{(2n-1)}$$

While all odd numbers are positive ($n>0$), you can take them out of the absolute and $2n+1$ produce the same series of number as $2n-1$ which is odd numbers:

$$\frac{|u_{n+1}|}{|u_n|}=\frac{|x^n|}{\color{red}{(2n+1)}}\cdot\frac{\color{red}{(2n-1)}}{|x^{n-1}|} = \frac{|x^n|}{|x^{n-1}|}=|\frac{x^n}{x^{n-1}}|=|x|$$

Hence:
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|u_{n+1}|}{|u_n|}=|x|$$

Comment: for $2n-1, n>0.$    
$n_1 = 1$ so $2(1)-1 = 1$,  
$n_2 = 2$ is $3$,  
$n_3 = 3$ is $5$ and  
$n_4 = 2$ is $7$  
  
however

for $2n+1, n>0$.  
$n_1 = 1$ so $2(1)+1 = 3$,  
$n_2 = 2$ is $5$,  
$n_3 = 3$ is $7$ and  
$n_4 = 2$ is $9$  
  
So although they both create a series of odd numbers, they are not equal for any given $n$ in the series. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Once the limits are applied I agree that $\frac{(2n-1)}{(2n+1)}=1$ since $[2(\infty)-1] = [2(\infty)+1]$

Comment: @Gineer: They produce the same series of numbers, one staring at $n=1$, the other at $n=0$.

Comment: Also, @Gineer, $|\frac{x^n}{x^{n-1}}|= |\frac{x \cdot x^{n-1}}{x^{n-1}}|$.